# How to handle uploaded files with Node-pdf-image?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, node-pdfkit

I'm trying to create an app where I allow a user to upload a PDF and then convert the first page of the uploaded file to an image. I am using https://github.com/mooz/node-pdf-image. I'm having trouble because I don't know what path to give to the tool. I don't have the full path of the PDF available on the user's computer, so I tried uploading the file to S3 and then using that path.

```
uploadFile(file, 'temps')
  .then(uploaded => {
    const pdfFile = new PDFImage(uploaded.secure_url);
    return pdfFile.convertPage(0);
  })
  .then(imagePath => console.log(imagePath))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

The above throws an error that fs.stat is not a function. How do you use this plugin and allow users to upload a file to an app?

Comment: Where does `file` come from and what value is it contain?

Comment: File comes from an input of type file. It looks like the following object. File looks like a javascript file:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: So then you're trying to use the `pdf-image` module in a browser? If so, that won't work...

Comment: No I'm making a call to server to do so.

Comment: The only reason above that I'm actually uploading a file to get a path. The S3 bucket is preventing the node-pdf-image package from writing to the bucket though. How do I get a path locally though? I realize I can't see the path on modern browsers (that's a security feature), but if I can avoid uploading I'd like to do so.